# What was wrong with my question?

Tags: discussion, deleting

Today I noticed that one of my questions
[("How to check which command was used to load a .sty file?")](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460473/how-to-check-which-command-was-used-to-load-a-sty-file)
was deleted. As the two consecutive downvotes, after nearly two months,
without any explanation didn't help me to improve the
question, could somebody please tell me what was wrong with
that question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's been auto-deleted. The StackOverflow model is about having questions with answers. Questions which attract low interest, low up-voting and no up-voted answers are periodically removed from public view by the 'back end'.

Looking at the question, I don't think there's anything wrong with it, and I'm surprised it didn't attract an answer. I'll undelete and post something.

Comment: So, how is it possible to get the `Tumbleweed`  badge if these questions are deleted?`Tumbleweed`  Asked a question with zero score, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week

Comment: @AndréC See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048. Questions that are not closed and have no answer only get deleted (quickly) if they have a negative score. If they question had not been downvoted (and I don't think the downvote was deserved) it would have survived (even indefinitely, because it has more than one comment, the threshold for the 365 day deletion).

Comment: Downvoting just to get roomba to delete a post is bad manners. Two consecutive downvotes after two months of inactivity smells like a coordinated effort to remove cruft from the site. I think there are better ways to accomplish the same thing. Ways that don't alienate users.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Two downvotes requires two separte users: I can't really imaging anyone has time for such stuff

Comment: @CrisLuengo Checking the votes on the question we are dicussing, I see only one downvote

Comment: I can't see that, don't have enough rep here. But OP said to have received two downvotes. Maybe one of them has been reverted since? On Stack Overflow there used to be a group that went around doing this, until it was pointed out what some of the side-effects are. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307009/7328782 .